# When are .dll addresses resolved when running an executable?

Tags: c++, dll, linker

When we have a C++ executable constructed from successfully compiled code, during the linking stage if I need to use a .dll the addresses will be correctly resolved in the executable to find them. Would this not suggest that if I drag the executable to a new computer that the addresses resolved during linking into the executable would be incorrect and pointing to memory address locations on the previous computer?

How is this issue resolved or when are the .dll addresses resolved so that the .exe can correctly find them?

So far it seems this may not be the case.

Comment: The are resolved  ultimately when the OS maps the dll into your process. A dll can be mapped into different processes at the same time and at different virtual addresses.

Comment: For one thing this exists since vista: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: @drescherjm Is this done on executing the executable? How does each new execution know where to find the .dll if I move it to a new PC?

Comment: Knowing were to find the DLL is a function of the OS and is described here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: @drescherjm Are you suggesting that when it finds the DLL, when you said "They are resolved ultimately when the OS maps the dll into your process". Is this done during executable startup? Is this why some code can successfully compile when it has no errors, but can have startup errors if a .dll is missing?

Comment: ***Is this done during executable startup?*** Not all dlls need to be loaded when the executable is started.

Comment: @drescherjm I see, so are you suggesting the .dll address are resolves when they loaded, and this happens during *runtime* when they're eventually needed?

Comment: Yes that is correct. They do have a module base address at compile time but its only a suggestion to the OS and since Vista with ASLR enabled it won't be used if your process get's randomized addresses.

Comment: @drescherjm Cheers, my final question is in relation to searching. Your previous link tells me the dll search order. Suppose I ship a project and do not include the required dll in the project, suppose I am shipping a game that requires DirectX. Is it a fair assumption that the user, if they were to have the required dll that it will be in either one of the locations mentioned. How can I guarantee that if I ship my project without the dll, that I can correctly search for it, is their a protocol that all installed dlls are in specific locations. How could this also avoid name conflicts? Cheers.

Comment: DirectX is a Microsoft api. It will be installed in system locations which are already in the  PATH environment variable.

Comment: Probably not the best example then, let's imagine it is a dll which is not in the Windows OS by default and would require some installation. When people install a program or download common dlls, is it expected that the default locations are in the dll search paths previously mentioned? I am just getting confused over if we ship our project, if the user does have dlls, how can I guarantee that they will be in the default locations that we search and make sure to find them?

Comment: Normally some other non Microsoft dlls you would install with your application and put them in your applications bin folder as part of the install process using an installer package. For my Qt based applications I write at work for the last 14+ years I have my NSIS based installer package these and other non OS required dlls in this `c:\program files\myapplication\bin` folder where I have all the executables for my software.

Comment: If you ship the dlls with your project and place them in your own `myapplication\bin` would that defeat the purpose of dlls? To my understanding a dll would ideally be in a location that can be shared by multiple applications to reduce unnecessary duplicated code space. To me it seems like you could be doing static linking and could include it in your .exe directly?

Comment: @J.Doe: It depends. At one time, yes, sharing a single DLL between many applications was generally considered a good thing. Reduced disk storage space and reduced RAM usage. But it can also lead to conflicts, where two apps require different versions of the DLL. Putting them in the application's directory still allows things like plug-ins, so somebody can add functionality long after the base application has shipped.

Comment: @JerryCoffin When reading this I thought you were going to say that two applications needed to use the same dll when both running at the same time. Wouldn't the versioning issue be resolved generally by naming conventions, e.g. example_v1.dll and example_v2.dll?

Comment: @JerryCoffin @drescherjm So what I am understanding from this is that when we download and install Microsoft Applications they're added to system paths to be found easily by other applications (e.g. DirectX). If they're custom dlls such as Qt code, they need to be shipped with the software and installed to a particular location using the installer (e.g NISS) so that they can be later found and used (e.g. Qt installed to `my_application\bin`. It is during runtime when the dll is loaded into a process where it is given a memory address space, the executable uses this to call the dll functions.

Comment: NSIS is one option: [https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) there are others: [https://wixtoolset.org/](https://wixtoolset.org/) Qt has its own tool: [https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html) however I use NSIS because it was one of the first installers that were supported by CMake: [https://cmake.org/](https://cmake.org/)

Comment: @J.Doe: A Microsoft *application* (as such) should act about like any other application. DirectX isn't an application though: it's part of the OS. It's generally allowed that if an application requires version X.Y of DirectX (or some other OS component), it's allowed to upgrade the OS to that version if needed (but it's generally required to use an OS upgrade package from Microsoft to do it).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Are you suggesting that all applications will then ship their own dlls for their application and the only dlls that are shared are those that come with the OS (DirectX can be later installed IIRC)? Even if it was possible for different applications to share their dlls this is typically not done to reduce complexity/versioning problems?

Comment: @J.Doe: Yeah, pretty much. Windows does quite a bit of jumping through hoops to deal with applications that install what are really their own, private DLLs into system directories (and early on, they even pretty much encouraged that). No need to make it worse though.